# node.js buffer strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to duplicate a buffer with slice of its arraybuffer, but the result buffer contains wrong value. Here is the example:

```
var sourceBuf = new Buffer(1);
sourceBuf.writeUInt8(1, 0);
var slice = sourceBuf.buffer.slice(0,1);
var resultBuf = new Buffer(slice);
console.log(resultBuf.readUInt8(0));
```

outputs `118`

In case of TypedArray all works as I at first expected:

```
var sourceBuf = new Uint8Array(1);
sourceBuf[0] = 1;
var slice = sourceBuf.buffer.slice(0,1);
var resultBuf = new Uint8Array(slice);
console.log(resultBuf[0]);
```

outputs `1`

So for now I want to know what causes such "different behavior".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to access the internal buffer and read the value. Try accessing the value like this:

```
var sourceBuf = new Buffer(1);
sourceBuf.writeUInt8(1, 0);
var slice = sourceBuf.slice(0,1); // Changed this line
var resultBuf = new Buffer(slice);
console.log(resultBuf.readUInt8(0));
```

There are two possible cases on how the error gets generated:

1. the binary value in the raw buffer gets interpreted the wrong way
2. robertKlep suggests that the `buffer`-property is uninitialized internally

In either way, accessing that property seemed to be the error.

Comment: Did you try yourself?

Comment: My debugger says "Number literal".

Comment: But did you actually try?

Comment: I did, otherwise I could not tell you what my debugger said

Comment: It yields the exact same value (118).

Comment: Wait, saw another issue

Comment: Yeah, it's the incorrect `slice` that causes the issue, not using `1` instead of `0x01` (which are basically the same thing).

Comment: Changed the answer. I guess it is due to the changed internal representation of a native UInt8-Buffer and a Number, as which the value gets interpreted.

Comment: I think that `.buffer` is uninitialized and contains (/points to) random data.

Comment: I don't think so, because it gave a 118 for me as well. Otherwise it's unlikely to produce the same (random) value

Comment: It actually points to the source code itself (if you make a bigger slice and log `resultBuf.toString()`). I guess that in an uninitialized state, it _may_ always point to that (`0x76` is the ASCII code for `v`, which is the first `v` of `var sourceBuf...`). Still random in terms of that it depends entirely on the source code :)

Comment: Maybe true, although I don't see how it could happen, as properties should always be initialized implicitly (otherwise, they should not exist). However, I added that possibility

Comment: The memory for buffers is, by default, uninitialized (documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe)), so they may contain _anything_. I guess that the same holds for `.buffer`.

Comment: I know what you mean, but `.buffer` is a sub-property of a `Buffer` object which got initialized (`var sourceBuf = new Buffer(1);`) correctly. That's why i am a little bit confused about that

Comment: The property itself is initialized (as in "it exists"), but its contents aren't. I think that `.buffer` isn't generally used for normal `Buffer` instances (it's only used when you create a new instance from a typed array), so it may be initialized lazily (if at all). It's also larger than the size of the parent buffer, which smells like some sort of optimization (it may be shared between all `Buffer` instances as a sort of default).

Comment: Anyway strange that it exists, if it's not used. This is a bug then, pretty sure. A non-initialized property of a properly initialized object must never be exposed to the js runtime in my opinion.